# Структура таблиц для подтверждения действия

Tags: python, база-данных, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

У меня есть активность, которую совершает пользователь (например, публикация вопроса). Активность может быть валидной или нет (например, валидная — вопрос по программированию, не валидная — спам). Я хочу реализовать очередь проверки активностей. Логика проверки: три человека просматривают активность, если два сходятся в каком–либо решении, активность отмечается таковой (но! количество проверок или логику проверки, возможно, придется менять в будущем).

Вопрос в том, как организовать таблички базы данных для этого? Сейчас у меня есть две таблички (`Action` и `Verification`). Когда пользователь что–то делает, создается запись в `Action`. Каждая же сделанная проверка записывается в `Verification`. Мне не нравится, что логика выставления флага валидности активности вынесена в код приложения, а не находится в базе.

Подскажите, как посоветуете изменить структуру базы данных, чтобы этого избежать, не усложняя последующую выборку валидных активностей?

```
class Action(db.Model):
    __tablename__       = 'action'

    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    activity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('activity.id'))
    creation_date= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    ...
    valid       = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    verified    = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    verified_date= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

class Verification(db.Model):
    __tablename__       = 'verification'

    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    action_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('action.id'))
    creation_date= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    is_valid    = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

**Обновление**

Сделал, как [порекомендовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000904/6) ЮрийСПб. Выборка, конечно, стала значительно сложнее. Например, так получаю список проверенных не отклоненных активностей:

```
subquery = db.session.query(
    Verification.action_id.label("action_id"),
    func.count(case([(Verification.is_valid == True, 1),], else_=0)).label("valid"),
    func.count(case([(Verification.is_valid == False, 1),], else_=0)).label("invalid")
).group_by(Verification.action_id).subquery()

action_query = db.session.query(Action).join(subquery, Action.id == subquery.c.action_id).filter(
    and_(subquery.c.valid > subquery.c.invalid, subquery.c.valid >= NEEDED_REVIEW_NUM))
```

Список активностей для проверки:

```
subquery = db.session.query(
    Verification.action_id.label("action_id"),
    func.count(case([(Verification.is_valid == True, 1),], else_=0)).label("valid"),
    func.count(case([(Verification.is_valid == False, 1),], else_=0)).label("invalid")
).group_by(Verification.action_id).subquery()

middle_query = db.session.query(Action.id).join(subquery, Action.id == subquery.c.action_id).filter(
    and_(subquery.c.valid > subquery.c.invalid, subquery.c.valid >= NEEDED_REVIEW_NUM))

action_query = db.session.query(Action).filter(~Action.id.in_(middle_query))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, поля `valid` и `verified` дублируют друг друга, т.к. активность не может быть `valid`/`!valid` пока её не верифицируют. А раз верификация это комбинация записей из другой таблицы, то в этой таблице она и не нужна. Следовательно не нужна и `verified_date`, т.к. её значение - это `creation_date` самой поздней `Verification` с соответствующим `action_id`. Таким образом, все 3 колонки можно выкинуть из таблицы.

Однако, отобразить их можно через представление (`View`). Там уже, в запросе формирования оного, можно написать нужные запросы для этих трёх колонок. В итоге их логику потом можно будет менять в БД. В итоге смена логики верификации не будет затрагивать таблицы `Action` и `Verification`, а будет требовать лишь смены запросов для формирования представления.